# Click to change background images using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I is it possible to edit the following jQuery code so that the user can chose the background image instead of the images just going round and round on repeat?

I can't quite figure out how to attach button selectors to each image. This is effect I'm after [Sprout theme](http://demo.wpbandit.com/sprout/demo/page-layouts/default/).

Thanks.

```
jQuery(function () {

    var imgArr = new Array( // relative paths of images
    'images/k2-in-skies.jpg', 'images/k2.jpg', 'images/kunhar-river.jpg', 'images/mitre-peak-baltoro.jpg', 'images/musa-ka-musalla.jpg', 'images/nanga-parbat.jpg', 'images/naran-valley.jpg');

    var preloadArr = new Array();
    var i;

    /* preload images */
    for (i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
        preloadArr[i] = new Image();
        preloadArr[i].src = imgArr[i];
    }

    var currImg = 1;
    var intID = setInterval(changeImg, 6000);

    /* image rotator */

    function changeImg() {
        $('#bg-imagesq').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000, function () {
            $(this).css('background', 'url(' + preloadArr[currImg++ % preloadArr.length].src + ') top center no-repeat');
        }).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 1000);
    }

});
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for three days running, most of that time I've had a migraine. I'm not a programer and don't have time to fully learn jquery

Answer (score 0):

Currently you use a fix element id called `#bg-imagesq`. What you have to do is to change to extract all elements with the img tag `$('img')`. If you don't want to apply your code to all images within the current page then add for the specific images a dummy css class and change it to `$('.bg-imagesCssClass')` (as an example).